# Graph with chromatic index 1 billion more than max degree?

Tags: graph-theory

For a simple graph, Vizing's Theorem says $\chi '(G)\leq \Delta(G)+1$, where $\chi '(G)$ is the chromatic index (minimum size of an edge coloring) and $\Delta(G)$ is the maximum degree. I want a graph with chromatic index 1 billion more than its highest degree, so obviously we will need some multiple edges.

My idea is to take the complete graph $K_n$ on $n$ vertices, for $n$ very large, and then add multiple edges.  Since the degree of $K_n$ is $n-1$ and it has $n(n-1)/2$ edges, it seems that when $n$ is very large we distribute multiple edges around the graph while keeping the degrees relatively small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon_multigraph).

Add an additional $999,999,999$ edges in parallel to each of the $3$ edges of $K_3$, and call this graph $G$. Then you can check $\chi'(G) = 3,000,000,000$ and $\Delta(G) = 2,000,000,000$.

Comment: Ok that works and is a bit simpler than what I was thinking about. Thanks!